# Non-existent table when RegisterTable | PocoDynaamo c#

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, pocodynamo

I am trying to use PocoDynamo query for my dynamoDb.

When I used POCO, I have non-existent table error.

```
var db = new PocoDynamo(dynamoDBClient);

db.RegisterTable<Table>();
```

I have faced this problem before. It was without PocoDynamo. And I fixed it like this:

```
...

_config = new DynamoDBOperationConfig
        {
            OverrideTableName = tableName,
        };

 var data = await dynamoDBContext.ScanAsync<Table>(null, _config).GetRemainingAsync();
```

Without _config the request does not work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I know nothing about poco but have you set your region in your DynamoDB Client?

Comment: Yes. If I using DynamoDBOperationConfig, I have not this problem.